# Berliner Weisse not souring

Tags: beer, bottling, sour

About 6 weeks ago, I made a simple Berliner Weisse. When I put it into primary, I pitched both yeast and the lactobacillus. It's been sitting in the primary ever since.

Yesterday, I took a taste sample because I'm wondering when I should bottle it. The sour character was pretty much non-existant.

I realize that sour character can take a while to develop. What I'm wondering is how I should wait for that to develop. Do I leave it in the fermenter for a few more months (will it carbonate at that point?)? If I bottle it now, will that develop in the bottle? If so, will that lead to bottle bombs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lactobacillus can be slow to develop but worth the wait. I would recommend bottling it and putting it in the basement for the next 6 months or so. You really can't rush these things. [Wyeast's website](http://www.wyeastlab.com/hb_lambicbrewing.cfm) on the subject recommends bottling after primary and waiting for a few months. It also has a ton of useful information on the subject.

Lactobacillus does produce CO2 from metabolic activity but I think it is slow enough that bottle bombs would not be a huge concern, you can just check the bottles every few weeks and if they get on the higher side of carbonation you can throw them in the fridge. Good luck!

Comment: It would depend on his gravity for the bottle bombs. Even if his gravity appears to be constant, it may just be going slow. I was reading another forum, where one guy had a sour drop from 1.020 to 1.008 over a 6 month period.